# How to get ordered list display for Top Emails in Forward Module?

Tags: emails

I'm using the [Forward](https://www.drupal.org/project/forward) module for keeping track of article content being emailed thru my site. I've been looking thru the module files to see where it is rendering the top5 (I modified it to Top10, instead) entries as an unordered list and have been unable to locate where this is.

Can anyone help with this?

Below is a sample of a basic unordered list showing from the Forward module block (I need this to render as an ordered list, instead):

[image: Basic unordered list showing from Forward module block...I need this to render as an ordered list, instead.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Go to `forward.module`

search for this "function forward_top5_list(" and change

```
"$query->range(0, 5);" from 5 to 10
```

this will work

Comment: Right. Thank you for this tip, but I've already done this part. I mentioned that already in my initial question, too...

My question only had to do w/ setting up the styling for the Top Ten Emailed list w/ an ordered list, instead of unordered bullets. I was wondering what hook/element inside forward.module I need to change to make that update...